# How to calculate a geometric sequence in C

Tags: c, for-loop, formula

I'm trying to write a code that calculates something similar to a geometric sequence.

[image]

I thought i did it, but when i looked at the solution, it seemed like i was doing something completely different.

There is a little twist to it though, the **X** value is in range from **Xmin** to **Xmax**, which means **xmin <= x <= xmax** and has a step of **Dx**.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main(){

    double xmin, xmax, dx, x, n = 1;
    long s = 0;

    printf("Input xmin, xmax, dx: ");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &xmin, &xmax, &dx);

    printf("\n       x          s\n=============================");

    for(x = xmin; x <= xmax; x += dx){
        s += pow(x,n);
        n++;
        printf("\n%10.3lf%10.3ld", x, s);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of what it outputs: (it goes from one to five, with a step of one)

[image]

Here's the actual solution, which i can't understand at all:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int n,i;
    double xmin, xmax, dx, x;

    printf("Input n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Input xmin, xmax, dx: ");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &xmin, &xmax, &dx);

    printf("\n       x          s\n=============================");

    for(x = xmin; x <= xmax; x += dx){
        double s = 0, p = 1;
        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            s += (p *= x);
        printf("\n%10.3f%10.3f", x, s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here's what it outputs: (I put **n** as 3 randomly, because i can't understand what it does)

[image]

My question is, what did i do wrong in my code? And why is there another loop in the *solution* with two variables that aren't even used anywhere?  It seems the output of my code isn't wrong, but i can't even understand the output of the *solution*.

Comment: The second code snippet appears correct. For each line of output, it picks a value for `x`, and then computes the sum of first `n` terms of the sequence `x`, `x^2`,  `x^3`, ..., `x^n` for that value of `x`. The outer loop picks the value of `x` to evaluate the series for, and the inner loop computes the series by summing different powers of `x`. Your code is doing something different. Each line is printing a partial sum of the sequence `x^n`, `(x+dx)^(n+1)`, `(x+dx+dx)^(n+2)`, ..., which isn't a geometric sequence.

Comment: @Brian Oh my god, thank you! I completely misunderstood how it should work and kept getting confused at the double loop for like 5 hours straight. Thanks again mate, cheers to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the main loop right, that being "for each value of `x`, from `xmin` to `xmax`, using `dx` as the step". However, you need to rethink how the algorithm works. Look back at the summation formula. Your answer is supposed to be calculated using the sum of `x` to the power of `i`, where `i` is every integer from `1` to `n`. So, when `n = 3`, your output should be equivalent to x^1 + x^2 + x^3 for each value of `x`.

1^1 + 1^2 + 1^3 = 1

2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 = 14

3^1 + 3^2 + 3^3 = 39

4^1 + 4^2 + 4^3 = 84

5^1 + 5^2 + 5^3 = 155

Your first loop is to repeat the formula for every value of `x`, but you need a nested loop because the formula you're using is a summation (i = 1 to n of x^i). You're also not supposed to carry the result of the last equation over to your new one.

Let me explain this: `s += (p *= x);` a little better. `s` (the sum) is initialized at 0 and `p` is initialized at 1. `p` is multiplied by `x` each loop, and added to `s` afterwards. The first time through the loop, `pow(p, 1)` is added to the sum. The second time, `pow(p, 2)` is added.  The third time, `x = pow(p, 3)` is added. So, if `n = 4` and `x = 2`, that would be `s = pow(2, 1) + pow(2, 2) + pow(2, 3) + pow(2, 4)`, or `s = 2 + 4 + 8 + 16`, or `s = 30`. This is equivalent to the sum of i from 1 to n of x^i.

I hope this helped, and if you want any further explanation, I'd be happy to give it.

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop

```
for(x = xmin; x <= xmax; x += dx){
    s += pow(x,n);
    n++;
    printf("\n%10.3lf%10.3ld", x, s);
}
```

the value of `n` is incremented in each iteration of the loop while in the second program

```
for(x = xmin; x <= xmax; x += dx){
    double s = 0, p = 1;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        s += (p *= x);
    printf("\n%10.3f%10.3f", x, s);
}
```

it is fixed for the given value of `x`.

Another problem is that you do not reset the variable s in each iteration of the loop for a given value of `x`.

```
s += pow(x,n);
```

Instead you need to write at least like

```
s = pow(x,n);
```

Though that will be in any case incorrect due to incrementing `n`.

Actually the second program calculates the formula for each `x` separately in the range `[xmin, xmax]` while your code calculates the formula while your program calculates the formula as whole for different values of x.